# Fire javascript retrieved from a websocket

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket

I am playing around with WebSockets at the moment, and I would like to have the following design pattern.

Connect to my websocket on a server, the server sends JavaScript to the browser to inform it how to interact with the user. I found the JQuery method getScript, which loads a script in the background, and executes it on load. I want to do a similar thing, but on the message received from the Websocket.

So, basically, what I want to do is...

```
// Create a socket
var socket = new WebSocket('myURL')

// Message received on the socket
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    executeJS(event.data);
}
```

What code would I need to replace executeJS to get this javascript to fire? Is it possible?

I suppose this question is not directly related to javascript, but how do I take a piece of text and execute it as Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use [`jQuery.globalEval`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/). Alternately you could use `eval`, but `globalEval` has some advantages in terms of the context in which it runs.

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is `eval()`.

Please don't forget that it sounds like `evil` for a reason ;)

Comment: There are situations where `eval` isn't evil. Not ***many***, mind. :-) But in this case, running script code from your own server, it's not fundamentally different from using a `script` element. (Except for scope issues.)

Comment: Indeed, but depending on what the script does it might be better to just send JSON and then process it.

Answer (score 2):

eval function evaluates code in *local scope*, for those code which should be evaluated in *global scope*, use *indirect eval*, a best way to call indirect eval is:

```
(1, eval)(yourCode);
```

There is also some other choice to execute code dynamically:

Also it is a good choice to use dynamic script element:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');

// detect browser or feature first, only one of these should be used
// for IE
script.text = yourCode;
// for other browser
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(yourCode));

var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.insertBefore(head, head.lastChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's use is generally frowned upon, the [eval()](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/eval.html) function would suit your needs here, depending on the complexity of the returned code.